# UITableView no requeue / redraw of cells on scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've noticed the cells are taken out of memory when scrolled out of view and then added back into memory when scrolled into view.

I get the performance reasons for this, but since my table only has a couple of cells out of view, is there a way to turn off this caching feature?

Comment: Why do you want to turn it off?

Comment: I'm at a fork in the road, one involves a lot more code with little benefit while the other involves a lot less code with the same benefit. The second approach is my question :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a different cell identifier for each index path.

That way, the `UITableView` won't be able to find a cell to dequeue, and a new one will be provided.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString * CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %d", indexPath.row, indexPath.section];
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    return cell;
}
```

You could also skip queuing/dequeing entirely, and retain a reference to them yourself, then just return them in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [myCells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Where `myCells` is an array holding your `UITableViewCell`s.

Comment: I am using the second method a lot on tables which do not scroll. It's a good way to go.